# How is KMI an application and not abstraction with MI in body in lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Let $K = \lambda zy.z$ (kestrel), $M = \lambda f.ff$ (mockingbird), $I = \lambda x.x$ (identity).

Now I believe $M$, I should be subsumed inside $K$'s function body but my lecture notes say that $K M I = M$. Can anyone explain how?

Another example that confused me from my slides:

$K \space I = \lambda ab .a \space \lambda x.x = \lambda ab.(a \lambda x.x) \text{ or } (\lambda ab.a)(\lambda x.x) $??
What's the right way to interpret and why?

Comment: What is the definition of $M$?

Comment: $M = \lambda f.ff$ @Taroccoesbrocco

Answer (score 1):

The $\lambda$-terms $K$, $I$, $M$ are defined as follows:
\begin{align}
I = \lambda x.x && K = \lambda zy.z && M = \lambda f.ff
\end{align}

This means that the $\lambda$-term $KI$ is the *whole* $\lambda$-term $K = (\lambda zy.z)$ applied to $I$, that is,
\begin{align}
KI &= (\lambda zy.z)I
\\
&\to_\beta  \lambda y.I 
\\
&= \lambda yx.x
\end{align}

When there is an application of three terms $RST$ (without any parentheses), by convention this means $(RS)T$, that is, first apply $R$ to $S$, and then the resulting $\lambda$-term is applied to $T$.
In particular:

\begin{align}
KMI &= ((\lambda zy.z)M)I
\\
&\to_\beta (\lambda y.M)I
\\
&\to_\beta M
\end{align}

Note that in the previous reduction, we never used the definition of $M$ or $I$. So, in general, for every $\lambda$-terms $S$ and $T$, we have $KST \to_\beta^* S$.